# Read and write files

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a text file, its content is(for example):

```
 388, 399, 100 
*Nset, nset=All, internal, generate
  1,  48,  1
*Elset, elset=All, internal, generate
  1,  35,   1
** Section:solidplane
*Solid Section, elset=All, material="rigid body"
*End Instance
```

Now I want use Mathematica read the above content and modify it;
for example,

(1)  I want the number "48 (3rd line)" to change to number"388 (1st line)",

(2)  I want the word "All (4th line)" to change to word "Whole",

How can I realize it?

So the output is:

```
 388, 399, 100
*Nset, nset=All, internal, generate
  1,  388,   1
*Elset, elset=Whole, internal, generate
  1,  35,   1
** Section:solidplane
*Solid Section, elset=All, material="rigid body"
*End Instance
```

I have used the function "ReadList" but failed...
Hope someone can help me

Comment: Maybe a combination of `Import` and `StringReplace`.

Comment: you should keep everything that you don't change in string format start with `Import[file,{"Text","Lines"}]`.  Then you need to cook up the appropriate string operations to make the desired changes.

Comment: I would not use _Mathematica_ for this. For a one-off situation, I would edit the file in a capable text editor, say, emacs. If there were a lot of files to edit, I would turn to a scripting language such as Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my proposition

Maybe the best format in this case is "CSV"
(also "Table" would be interesting )

You'll have to customize myPath and "material.txt"

```
myPath = NotebookDirectory[];
file = ToFileName[myPath, "material.txt"]
f = Import[file, "CSV"]
```

once the file is loaded, it appears without quotes in Mma
 (I saved it previously in the actual directory for this example)
you may get

```
{{388, 399, 100}, {"*Nset", " nset=All", " internal", 
  " generate"}, {1, 48, 1}, {"*Elset", " elset=All", " internal", 
  " generate"}, {1, 35, 
  1}, {"** Section:solidplane"}, {"*Solid Section", " elset=All", 
  " material=\"rigid body\""}, {"*End Instance"}}
```

you can access now e.g. 399 in line=1, item=2 (you don't have to write line or item, this is just for clear explanation)

f[[line = 1, item = 2]]

so doing your questions 1) and 2) with

```
f[[line = 3, item = 2]] = f[[line = 1, item = 1]]
f[[line = 4, item = 2]] = "elset=Whole"
f
```

and saving again your changes with

```
Export[file, f]
```

and reimport for verifying

```
Import[file, "CSV"]
```